# How to erase subtle jumps in wave form?

Tags: c#

need a light here.
I have a float[] and between the floats inside this array there are some values that suddenly have fluctuations like in the first part of the image bellow.
[image]

What I want is some function to turn this first part into something similar to the second part. Also, I've tryed derivative method and it works almost fine, the problem is that sometimes like in sinusoidal wave it just doesn't give me the right result. No need for coding for me, just want a push. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're looking for _signal smoothing_.

Comment: Also, [here's an answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/248860/272607) from the Math SE which, I think, will give you some ideas.

Comment: You can fix exactly this case with some naive logic. There is a sudden change of value by `9` units. You can start monitoring for such change (e.g. if new value is different from old one by `>5`) from some moment  and when it occurs - offset further points until same big change occurs in another direction. As a kind of postprocessing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Workout the average value over the previous `X` nodes.
2. Decide on what your maximum decrease/increase fluctuation percentage is.
3. If a node exceeds this threshold, replace it with the average value including the fluctuation value.

eg. Take the below sequence.

> 40,39,41,42,42,43,44,43,42,43,44,45,46,45,44,46,47,**33,32,33,34**,44,45,46,47

Lets say that **33,32,33,34** all exceed our threshold and we are averaging the previous 10 entries.

Replace all values exceeding the threshold with the value of this calculation, where Y is the value that exceeds the threshold.

```
(Previous Average + Y) / X + 1
```

In our example, 33 would be replaced by `(445 + 33)/11 = 43.45` etc.

Comment: Hi, trat would work pretty well, but it brings another problem. For example, if I have a sinusoidal waveform and it doesn't have any "jumps" your idea would correct all the waveform and make it plain and the same thing would happen to other waveforms that doesn't have a jump, or am I wrong?

Comment: @MarceloViníciusdePaula You would only correct the value if it exceeds your defined threshold. If you don't have any jumps then it would use the original value.

Comment: Thanks, you gave me the idea, I did some modifications on it and now it is working, I just have to work on that Threshold factor so it changes itself according to the data array I receive.
And again, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to use a Lowpass filter or Kalman filter.

Comment: I personally used Kalman for removing noise and irregularities from an accelerometer.